# Validate image width while uploading?

Tags: fine-uploader

I want to restrict end user to upload multiple images using drag and drop feature, should not be greater than 1000 pixels wide. I have read http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/validation.html
it's discuss fineuploader provide built-in validators for image dimensions.I have used image.maxWidth attribute but it's not work.

```
validation: {
                    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg','jpg','png', 'gif'],
                    maxWidth:1000,
           },
```

Please suggest what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am doing wrong,the correct way is :

```
validation: {
                    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg','jpg','png', 'gif'],
                     image:{maxWidth:1000},
           },
```

You can find more validation attribute details here :

http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/hotfix_4.1.1/features/validation.html

Comment: That is a very old link.  I would suggest using this one instead: http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/validation.html